# Where to learn Tizen Native Wearable Basics

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I'm trying to develop an app for my Galaxy Watch which runs on Tizen. I'm not able to find any wholesome tutorial out there for Tizen. Do you mind recommending me some?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to use .NET and C# for your Watch application?

Click [here](https://developer.tizen.org/development/training/.net-application/getting-started/creating-your-first-tizen-wearable-.net-application)!

You can also use Native Application Model (C based) for your Watch application.
Plz, visit [Tizen developer site](https://developer.tizen.org)

Comment: Thank you soo much. In line with that, do you have any idea what is the RelativeLayout (android xml) equivalent in Tizen xml? Thanks

Comment: Tizen supports Xamarin Forms. Refer to this page. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout)